# Simple clicker in unity and error that i can't understand C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make simple clicker in Unity. I was using a internet tutorial and i tried to do something by myself. All i wanted to do was changing one thing from float to long cause i wanted to make the biggest amount of "clicks" as i actually can. 
Error:'ping.toInt64(float)' must have a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial

Code:

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using System;

    public class ping : MonoBehaviour {

    public UnityEngine.UI.Text gpc;
    public UnityEngine.UI.Text GoldDisplay;
    /*public long gold = 0.00f;*/

    public static long toInt64(
    float gold = 0.00f
    );
    public int goldperclick = 1; 

    void Update(){
     GoldDisplay.text = "Ping: " + gold;
     gpc.text = goldperclick + "ping/click";
 }

     public void Clicked(){
     gold += goldperclick;
}

}
```

Comment: you have to provide _code_ for `toInt64`, like the other methods here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring a method, `toInt64` but not implementing it. Look at the different between that method and your `Update` method. (What are you trying to accomplish with `toInt64`?)

```
public static long toInt64()
{
    return Convert.ToInt64(gold);
}
```

Of course, you'll have to uncomment your definition of `gold` on the line above.

Comment: I found it on microsoft site and i thought that it should work. I have no idea how to properly convert it to long.

Comment: Thank you so much. How can i use gold in the other files? I mean I have ping.cs(which you can see here) itemmanager.cs in which I'm using ping.gold and it's bad now, but it worked before the changes.

Comment: It sounds like you want to access ping.gold outside of the ping class, is that correct? If so, you could always change `gold` to be a property with `public long gold { get; private set; }`.

Comment: if it's not a problem can i ask you something else? I've got a new error: goldpersec.cs(20,25) Cannot implicity convert type  'long' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: here is a code 
public int GetGoldPerSec(){
  int tick = 0;
  foreach (ItemManager item in items) {
   tick += item.count * item.tickValue;
  }
  return tick;
 }
 public void AutoGoldPerSec(){
  ping.gold += GetGoldPerSec ();
 }

Comment: I mean which line within that subset? Is the warning on the `tick += ...` line?

Comment: I guess it's here:
 ping.gold += GetGoldPerSec ();

Comment: Try `ping.gold += (long) GetGoldPerSec();`

Comment: Still nothing ;/.

Comment: Or it means tha tthe problem is with the line that you mentioned before.

Comment: Well, that error is saying you're trying to convert a `long` to an `int` - which you can do, but it must be explicit because there could be data loss. There's a good introduction to type conversions here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx . In particular, the syntax `int myint = (int) someLongValue;` is probably what you're looking for.

Is there any reason you're using `int tick` instead of `long tick`?

Comment: Ok i will try this one. One more thing: public long gold = 0.00f;  why it's saying that constant value '0' cannot be converted to 'long'?

Comment: `long` is an integer type, e.g. it cannot have any decimals. :)

Comment: How about An object reference is required to access non-static member ping.gold. here: 
public static long toInt64()
 {
  return Convert.ToInt64(gold);
 }

Answer (score -1):

change this:

```
public static long toInt64(
float gold = 0.00f
);
```

to this:

```
float gold;
public static long toInt64(){
    gold = 0.00f;
}
```

I'm just correcting your formatting. I have no idea what logic are you trying to implement. good luck

Comment: Thank you. I don't even know C# that's why it looks hillarious.